# Add View over ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to create calendar. I want to use ListView as Hours For day viewing .

I came across a problem  For showing events in day. I use my View as event.When I want to show my View between two hours, every thing is good(because simply in getView() method in adapter I inflate my View and show it ) but I can't show my View between two times that aren't between two hours.

For example I can't show my View between 2:30 and 3:30. I want to add my View over ListView.

This is ICS calendar, I want some thing like this:
[image]
You can see event between 5:30 and 6:30.

Answer (score 2):

Use Relative layout to create 'layers'. Your bottom layout will be ListView and TextView as a top. But this layout can cause a lot of headache.

I recommend to create custom component (based on LinearLayout) where you can draw hours yourself and place TextView using absolute positioning.

Comment: Tnx ruX. If I use Relative layout is it make some problem for scrolling? I guess it makes problem for scrolling and I should sync scrolling of ListView and scrolling of top layer.

Comment: @HoseinBitaraf you can specify height and width of your component equals to ListView. When listview is has been scrolled (`onScroll` event) recalculate positions of TextView

Comment: i think it will be one hell of a messy solution :)

Comment: @Waqas may be. It's just first thought ;)